# get "caller" filename from within included file

Tags: tcl

I have a bunch of different scripts that include another script (we can loosely call it a library) and I am trying to figure out how (from the included script) to get the name of the script that included it. The problem is that the “info script” command returns JasperGold (the tool name) rather than the script name I am running *on* the tool. Any idea how to do this?

A.tcl:

```
source B.tcl
…
```

B.tcl

```
# Some command that will return “A.tcl”
…
```

Comment: Have you had a look at what `info frame` can report? That *might* work... or might not, as it is very sensitive to the calling environment. (It peers deeper into the details of Tcl's implementation than most supported commands.) The tricky bit here (as a general Tcl support channel) is that `include` is custom, and could do all sorts of confounding things. We really need to know more...

Comment: @DonalFellows source seems to also work so I have changed it to that to keep it more vanilla .tcl

Comment: The tcl interpreter was modified by the EDA vendor which broke some of the standard functionality which is why I was confused. Normally yes the 'info frame' is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more fleshed-out example:

```sh
$ cat -n a.tcl
     1  puts "this is [info script]"
     2  source b.tcl
```

```sh
$ cat -n b.tcl
     1  proc main {} {
     2      puts "this is [info script]"
     3      c
     4  }
     5  proc c {} { d }
     6  proc d {} {
     7      set n [info frame]
     8      puts "absolute frames"
     9      for {set i $n} {$i > 0} {incr i -1} {
    10          puts [list $i [info frame $i]]
    11      }
    12      puts "relative frames"
    13      for {set i 0} {$i > -$n} {incr i -1} {
    14          puts [list $i [info frame $i]]
    15      }
    16  }
    17
    18  main
```

```sh
$ tclsh a.tcl
this is a.tcl
this is b.tcl
absolute frames
5 {type source line 10 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {info frame $i} proc ::d level 0}
4 {type source line 5 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {d } proc ::c level 1}
3 {type source line 3 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {c } proc ::main level 2}
2 {type source line 18 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd main level 3}
1 {type source line 2 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/a.tcl cmd {source b.tcl} level 3}
relative frames
0 {type source line 14 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {info frame $i} proc ::d level 0}
-1 {type source line 5 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {d } proc ::c level 1}
-2 {type source line 3 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd {c } proc ::main level 2}
-3 {type source line 18 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/b.tcl cmd main level 3}
-4 {type source line 2 file /Users/glennjackman/tmp/a.tcl cmd {source b.tcl} level 3}
```

Comment: The issue with `info script` is that it is only accurate *while the script is being sourced*. You gave to save the value in a variable (probably in your per-package namespace) if you want to use it later. `info frame` provides more detail and works later, but is very sensitive to implementation details in other ways (e.g., it "sees" `uplevel`, a very unusual capability).

Comment: Thanks Donal for the details. s/gave/have/

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using [`info frame`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M15) as Donal suggested? For a basic case, this works for me:

```
# B.tcl (top level)
dict get [info frame 1] file
```